# Rails "follow" relationship controller issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, relationship

I am working on an app where users' "projects" can follow "plant" objects from the database. I am getting the following error for the create action in my "Prelationships" controller (Plant Relationships that connect Users' projects to fixed "plant" objects) when I hit "Follow" for any number of plant objects in my app:

**"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]"**

I realize this is a big question, and yes, I'm pretty much a newbie. All the migrations should be fine. I appreciate any help--even if it means suggesting a whole new way of tackling this issue.

Here's what my controller, called "Prelationships", looks like:

```
class PrelationshipsController < ApplicationController  
 def create                                                    
  @plant = Plant.find(params[:prelationship][:pfollowed_id])
  @project.follow!(@plant)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @project }
    format.js
  end
 end  
end
```

And my "Prelationships" model:

```
class Prelationship < ActiveRecord::Base                          
 attr_accessible :pfollowed_id

   belongs_to :pfollower, :class_name => "Project"
   belongs_to :pfollowed, :class_name => "Plant"

   validates :pfollower_id, :presence => true
   validates :pfollowed_id, :presence => true
end
```

And my "Projects" model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base                    
attr_accessible :title, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :state      

 belongs_to :user        
 has_many :prelationships, :foreign_key => "pfollower_id",
                        :dependent => :destroy   
 has_many :pfollowing, :through => :prelationships, :source => :pfollowed  

 def pfollowing?(pfollowed)
   prelationships.find_by_pfollowed_id(pfollowed)  
 end  

 def pfollow!(pfollowed)
  prelationships.create!(:pfollowed_id => pfollowed.id)
 end
end
```

And my "plant" model:

```
class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base      

 has_many :prelationships, :foreign_key => "pfollowed_id",
                        :class_name => "Prelationship"
 has_many :pfollowers, :through => :reverse_prelationships, 
                        :source => :pfollower   
end
```

And, finally, my "_plants_form" partial for the view:

```
<%= form_for @project.prelationships.build(:pfollowed_id =>
                                           @project_id) do |f| %>
  <%= collection_select(:prelationships, :pfollowed_id, Plant.all, :id, :name, 
  options = {:prompt => "Select your plants"}, :class => "listselect") %>  
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Pfollow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the error from my log:

```
 Started POST "/prelationships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-20 23:31:57 +0100
 Processing by PrelationshipsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",       
 "authenticity_token"=>"NKqa1f0M2yPLQDHbRLnxl3SiwBeTus/1q1hpZjD7hgY=",      
 "prelationships"=>{"pfollowed_id"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Pfollow"}
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms

 NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
 You might have expected an instance of Array.
 The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
 app/controllers/prelationships_controller.rb:4:in `create'

 Rendered /Users/mmelone12/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-  
 3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.4ms)
 Rendered /Users/mmelone12/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-   
 3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb    
 (30.6ms)
 Rendered /Users/mmelone12/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack- 
 3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within 
 rescues/layout (37.1ms)
```

Comment: can you paste the back trace of the error?

Comment: pls let me know if you need anything else to help crack this

Comment: Where is `@project` being instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Like Swanand point out, you should initialize `@project` object inside `:create action`. Like `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])` if you do not do it with a `before_filter`.

If you already instantiated `@project` before, see what happens when you manually try to retrieve `@plant` object in Rails console `Plant.find(1)`

Comment: ah, yes! Thank you. A very big oversight. That fixes that question... although I'm still having an issue even after inserting that snippet in the `:create action`, I'm now receiving a `Couldn't find Project without an ID` error message after submitting on the `_plants_form` partial. I'm guessing there's some disconnect on my RESTful actions, though any parting thoughts of what mistake I'm making would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check nested routes. They might help you a lot. Read/watch especially Ryan's take on it. (Railcasts #196 + #197). You might also want to check inherited_resources and simple_form gems. Enjoy coding.